# Create a Typescript library with demo page using Parcel 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundler, parceljs

I'm creating my first Typescript library that exports some functions.

The structure of the project is this:

```
myProject
  |_ assets/
    |_ logo.png
  |_ coverage
    |_ ...some stuff
  |_ demo
    |_ index.html
    |_ index.ts
    |_ style.css
  |_ dist
    |_ ...
  |_ dist-demo
    |_ ...
  |_ node_modules
  |_ src
    |_ lib/
      |_ types.ts
      |_ index.ts
    |_ index.ts
  |_ .gitignore
  |_ package.json
```

`index.ts` is:

```
export { sayHello } from './lib'
```

`lib/index.ts` is:

```
export function sayHello() {
  console.log('Hello')
}
```

(Obviously, this is only an easy example, the important thing is the structure).

I decided to create a demo page: I created the demo folder and inside it, I created `index.html`, `index.ts`, `style.css`.

Then I decided to use Parcel as bundler. Keep in mind that I'm a junior developer.

So my `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "myLib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": "https://github.com/.../myLib.git",
  "author": "...",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "module": "dist/module.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "parcel watch",
    "build": "parcel build",
    "build:demo": "parcel build demo/index.html --dist-dir dist-demo",
    "start:demo": "parcel demo/index.html",
    "compile": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc --outDir dist",
    "compile-watch": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc -w --outDir dist",
    "prepublish": "yarn compile",
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/packager-ts": "^2.1.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-types": "^2.1.0",
    "parcel": "latest",
    "typescript": ">=3.0.0"
  }
}
```

If I run `yarn build`, the build is created in `dist` folder.
Then, I would use the bundled file and test it in the demo page, so my demo files are:

`demo/index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Say hello</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./index.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`demo/index.ts`:

```
import { sayHello } from '../dist/module' // <-- ???

sayHello()
```

If I run `yarn start:demo`, the demo page on `http://localhost:1234/` doesn't work: `404. Page not found`.
Why?

And then, how can I create a public site with the content of the demo page. I think to deploy it using Netflify.
What's wrong with my package.json configuration?

Summary: what I would like is to create a library that:

- exports some functions
- a website (the demo page) containing, for example, some visual examples.

Thanks a lot!

---

I tried also:

```json
"lib": "dist/main.js",
  "demo": "dist-demo/main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "module": "dist/module.js",
  "targets": {
    "lib": {
      "source": "src/index.ts",
      "distDir": "./dist",
      "isLibrary": true
    },
    "demo": {
      "source": "demo/index.html",
      "distDir": "./dist-demo"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "parcel watch src/index.ts",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.ts --dist-dir dist",
    "build:demo": "parcel build demo/index.html --dist-dir dist-demo",
    "start:demo": "parcel demo/index.html",
    "compile": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc --outDir dist",
    "compile-watch": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc -w --outDir dist",
    "prepublish": "yarn compile",
    "check": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
```

but it doesn't work

---

Now I have:

```
  ...
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "module": "dist/module.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "parcel watch ./src/index.ts",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.ts --dist-dir dist",
    "build:demo": "parcel build ./demo/index.html --dist-dir dist-demo",
    "start:demo": "parcel ./demo/index.html --dist-dir dist-demo",
    "compile": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc --outDir dist",
    "compile-watch": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc -w --outDir dist",
    "prepublish": "yarn compile"
  },
  ...
```

`yarn build` and `yarn start:demo` work but when I run `yarn build:demo`, I get:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ parcel build ./demo/index.html --dist-dir dist-demo
 Build failed.

@parcel/core: No transformers found for demo/index.html with pipeline: 'types'.

  /Users/.../node_modules/@parcel/config-default/index.json:3:3
     2 |   "bundler": "@parcel/bundler-default",
  >  3 |   "transformers": {
  >    |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  4 |     "types:*.{ts,tsx}": ["@parcel/transformer-typescript-types"],
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  5 |     "bundle-text:*": ["...", "@parcel/transformer-inline-string"],
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  6 |     "data-url:*": ["...", "@parcel/transformer-inline-string"],
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  7 |     "worklet:*.{js,mjs,jsm,jsx,es6,cjs,ts,tsx}": [
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  8 |       "@parcel/transformer-worklet",
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  9 |       "..."
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 10 |     ],
  >    | ^^^^^^
  > 11 |     "*.{js,mjs,jsm,jsx,es6,cjs,ts,tsx}": [
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 12 |       "@parcel/transformer-babel",
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 13 |       "@parcel/transformer-js",
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hey, I was just successful with your original setup, with just a couple minor differences.  One thing you might try is adding `.js` on your `sayHello` import:

```js
import { sayHello } from '../dist/module.js'
```

Also, I don't have any `targets` specified in `package.json`

Comment: another key point, I'm using npm!

Answer (score 0):

Parcel build by default everything he needs in the `dist` folder until you specify another one using the `--dist-dir` flag. So your problem here is that the `build` command will produce a `dist` folder like:

```
dist/main.js
dist/module.js
dist/index.d.ts
```

But when you run `start:demo`, parcel also compile the files in `dist`:

```
dist/index.125bf0c5.js
dist/index.html
dist/main.js
dist/module.js
dist/index.d.ts
```

Here come the weird part, if you delete the `dist` folder and re-run the build steps, the `start:demo` files are no more added (looks like a bug). So the `index.html` will be not be found.

To fix this problem, I suggest you to separate the different `dist` folders: `dist` for the library only and `dist-demo` for website (prod and dev):

```json
    "build": "parcel build",
    "start:demo": "parcel ./demo/index.html --dist-dir dist-demo",
```

Comment: Thank you, and what about building the demo page? I tried `"build:demo": "parcel build ./demo/index.html --dist-dir dist-demo` but I get `@parcel/core: No transformers found for demo/index.html with pipeline: 'types'.`. More details in the main message

Comment: @whitecircle The second issue is way more complex than the initial issue :/ The problem come from the `source`, `main`, `module` and`types` declaration in your `package.json` those are meant for the build of the library but not the website. I would recommend you to extract the website out of the library or use a yarn [workspace](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/). I created for you a poc https://github.com/johannchopin/poc-parceljs-and-yarn-workspaces.

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't know yarn workspaces, interesting but they hace to be used with `"private": true` that is strange for a library. I mean, for the moment my library is obviously private, but in the future it can be published on npm and so it will be public so I can't use yarn workspaces

Comment: Read more about workspaces in the doc. I didn't do it for the example but you should have normally 2 workspaces: 1 for the demo and the other for the library. Then the root `package.json` will contains common packages and the library will have his own with the attribute `private` set to `true`.

Comment: Were you able to get this working for the demo project? I am trying to do the same thing now